# Segmentation Fault: (Core dumped) while trying to modify array in fonction

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, pthreads

i struggling throug this error in c and i can't get my fingers on.
I am making a rock paper scissor game in c with the thread for exercice.
I want to modify an **array** **tabJoueur** of two struct element **Joueur** in a function.
But even when i try to display the value of the array, i got a segmentation fault.

The array **tabJoueur** look like this

```
Joueur tabJoueur[2];
```

The struct **Joueur** look like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int coup;
    char *nom;
    int score;
} Joueur;
```

Here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    
    Joueur tabJoueur[2];
    pthread_t id[2];
    
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&cle,NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        Joueur *args = (Joueur*)malloc(sizeof(Joueur));
        args = &tabJoueur[i];
        args->nom = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        args->coup = -1;
        args->score = 0;
        pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,functionJoueur,args);
    }
    
    while(tabJoueur[0].score < 3  || tabJoueur[1].score < 3)
    {
        if (tabJoueur[0].coup != -1 && tabJoueur[1].coup != -1)
        {
            if (pthread_mutex_lock(&cle) == 0)
            {
                //Joueur (*pJoueur)[2] = malloc(sizeof(Joueur)*2);
                //pJoueur = &tabJoueur;
                jugeChifoumi(&tabJoueur);
                //free(pJoueur);
                
                for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
                {
                    tabJoueur[i].coup = -1;
                }
                
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&cle);
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        if (tabJoueur[i].score == 3)
        {
            printf("Victoire de %s", tabJoueur[i].nom);
        }
        printf("%s Dit au revoir", tabJoueur[i].nom);
        free(tabJoueur[i].nom); // on libère la mémoire du nom
    }
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++)
    {
        pthread_cancel(id[i]); // on détruit les threads
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&cle); // on détruit la cle mutex
    
    return 1;
}
```

The problem happen in the while loop when the main get the mutex.
Here i give in a function called jugeChifoumi that look like this.

```
void jugeChifoumi(Joueur (*tabCoup)[2])
{
    printf("%s joue %d  et %s joue %d.\n", tabCoup[0]->nom, tabCoup[0]->coup, tabCoup[1]->nom, tabCoup[1]->coup);
    int resultat = tabCoup[0]->coup - tabCoup[1]->coup;
    if (resultat == -2 || resultat == 1)
    {
        tabCoup[0]->score = tabCoup[0]->score + 1; // on rajoute 1 dans le score du joueur 1
        printf("%s a gagné! %d points contre %d points.\n", tabCoup[0]->nom, tabCoup[0]->score, tabCoup[1]->score);
    }
    else if (resultat == -1 || resultat == 2)
    {
        tabCoup[1]->score = tabCoup[1]->score + 1; // on rajoute 1 dans le score du joueur 2
        printf("%s a gagné! %d points contre %d points.\n", tabCoup[1]->nom, tabCoup[0]->score, tabCoup[1]->score);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Match nul\n");
    }
}
```

Even when i try to access to the element of my array, i believe that i go in a forbidden memory.
But i don't get it why it does this, i was thinking i could modify my array tabJoueur just by putting his address by (&) and modify it by a pointer in the parameters of my function.
I can understand that is basic knowledge in pointers but after seing so many post that give different solutions, i start to get confused.

for example, some people suggest `int *array` and other suggest `int array[size]`, some other talk about using a pointer like this:

```
Joueur (*p)[2] = malloc(sizeof(Joueur)*2);
p = tabJoueur;
jugeChifoumi(p);
```

but i don't get it why.
Some tips would be really nice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: one problem I see.. you're treating `nom` as a string, but only allocating space for 1 character (`args->nom = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));`). A string needs at least two characters to make room for the `NUL` terminator.

Comment: I also don't see any code that actually writes data to `nom`, so even after you fix the memory allocation, you'll still invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing it.

Comment: It's because it's the thread code that write data in nom but that is not what i am struggling to. I can access to my tabCoup because it throw me segmentation fault

Comment: if you're writing more than one character to `nom`, you're overrunning the buffer and invoking undefined behavior. As long as you're treating a single-char `nom` as a string and trying to `printf` it with the `%s` format specifier, you're invoking undefined behavior. UB can certainly manifest itself as a segfault.

Comment: I have put ```(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);``` but i still got a segmentation fault so the error come from my function jugeChifoumi

Comment: I would recommend learning the basics of C before attempting to write multithreaded code.

Comment: Good new, i have test some few things and i see that i get a segmentation fault when i try to access into the tabJoueur[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are in jugeChifoumi and the call to it.  Arrays in C are already passed by reference.

You should change the following:

```
void jugeChifoumi(Joueur (*tabCoup)[2])
{
    printf("%s joue %d  et %s joue %d.\n", tabCoup[0]->nom, tabCoup[0]->coup, tabCoup[1]->nom, tabCoup[1]->coup);
    int resultat = tabCoup[0]->coup - tabCoup[1]->coup;
    if (resultat == -2 || resultat == 1)
    {
        tabCoup[0]->score = tabCoup[0]->score + 1; // on rajoute 1 dans le score du joueur 1
        printf("%s a gagné! %d points contre %d points.\n", tabCoup[0]->nom, tabCoup[0]->score, tabCoup[1]->score);
    }
    else if (resultat == -1 || resultat == 2)
    {
        tabCoup[1]->score = tabCoup[1]->score + 1; // on rajoute 1 dans le score du joueur 2
        printf("%s a gagné! %d points contre %d points.\n", tabCoup[1]->nom, tabCoup[0]->score, tabCoup[1]->score);
    }
```

... to this with a different declaration and "->" changed to "." everywhere.

```
void jugeChifoumi(Joueur tabCoup[2])
{
    printf("%s joue %d  et %s joue %d.\n", tabCoup[0].nom, tabCoup[0].coup, tabCoup[0].nom, tabCoup[1].coup);
    int resultat = tabCoup[0].coup - tabCoup[1].coup;
    if (resultat == -2 || resultat == 1)
    {
        tabCoup[0].score = tabCoup[0].score + 1; // on rajoute 1 dans le score du joueur 1
        printf("%s a gagné! %d points contre %d points.\n", tabCoup[0].nom, tabCoup[0].score, tabCoup[1].score);
    }
    else if (resultat == -1 || resultat == 2)
    {
        tabCoup[1].score = tabCoup[1].score + 1; // on rajoute 1 dans le score du joueur 2
        printf("%s a gagné! %d points contre %d points.\n", tabCoup[1].nom, tabCoup[0].score, tabCoup[1].score);
    }
```

You should change the call from:

```
            jugeChifoumi(&tabJoueur);
```

to:

```
            jugeChifoumi(tabJoueur);
```

Your declaration of tabJouer in main() as a local variable is just fine as is.

Comment: That is exactly what i did before you answer and it work!
For some reason, array can be give by reference without using & because it already point to the first element as reference, it does contain the adress of the first element.
And ```Joueur tabCoup[2]```is the same as ```Joueur (*tabCoup)[2]```.
Thanks you very much.